# Autoit Send Email UTF-8

Tags: email, utf-8, character-encoding, autoit

Trying to send an email with UTF-8 chars from AutoIt with the **_INetMail** function results in not correctly displayed chars in the resulting email document.

Example code:

```
#include <Inet.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $sAddress = "me@you.com"
Local $sSubject = "Special chars öäüß"
Local $sBody = "My body text with special UTF-8 öäüß chars"
_INetMail($sAddress, $sSubject, $sBody)
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Its something about the header to set

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

But how to inject it into the **_INetMail** function?

```
Func _INetMail($sMailTo, $sMailSubject, $sMailBody)
    Local $iPrev = Opt("ExpandEnvStrings", 1)
    Local $sVar, $sDflt = RegRead('HKCU\Software\Clients\Mail', "")
    If $sDflt = "Windows Live Mail" Then
        $sVar = RegRead('HKCR\WLMail.Url.Mailto\Shell\open\command', "")
    Else
        $sVar = RegRead('HKCR\mailto\shell\open\command', "")
    EndIf
    Local $iRet = Run(StringReplace($sVar, '%1', _INetExplorerCapable('mailto:' & $sMailTo & '?subject=' & $sMailSubject & '&body=' & $sMailBody)))
    Local $iError = @error, $iExtended = @extended
    Opt("ExpandEnvStrings", $iPrev)
    Return SetError($iError, $iExtended, $iRet)
EndFunc   ;==>_INetMail
```

I assume it must integrated somewhere in here:

```
_INetExplorerCapable('mailto:' & $sMailTo & '?subject=' & $sMailSubject & '&body=' & $sMailBody)
```

But I dont get it to work. 
How to set the correct charset at the header for that?

Thx

Comment: AutoIt behaves difficult when UTF-8 is concerned: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/146129-inetmail-and-spécial-chars/